# AVD manager won't start anylonger in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

When I press the AVD Manager button in Eclipse, **nothing happens** (and I mean nothing) ...

When I try to run an app, I get the message "No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device? When I click "Yes", I get the "Android Device Chooser" Window. This is completely empty (no devises listed). So I check the radio button "launch new Android Virtual Device", which activates the "Manager" button. But when I click this button, **again nothing happens** ...

So, for some reason my AVD Manager won't start up.

PS: **The AVD Manager did work before**, when I was going through the "Hello World" exercise. For some reason it stopped working. I tried reinstalling the whole SDK and Eclipse thing, to no avail. I work with Windows 7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same issue once. I finally ended up reinstalling it...

Comment: plz go to window in eclipse and select preferences then select android and plz give path of android location

Comment: I guess you can click on AVD Manager exclusively (without trying to run an application) and click on NEW on the right hand side and create a new AVD.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem. so i uninstalled the sdk (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk) and **deleted the C:\Users\hp.android folder**  (make sure to delete this folder else the problem will exist even after reinstallation). upon reinstallation everything worked perfectly...

Comment: It finally worked by first erasing all user related data of Eclipse, and then reinstalling it

Answer (score 0):

You might have not set the sdk path. to do so,

```
step1: go to windows menu option 

step2: click on preference,

step3: select android

step 4: change the android sdk path and restart eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install or reinstall the AVD system image in Android SDK Manager in Eclipse.